# GROUP BY month when selecting a date Teradata SQL assistant

Tags: sql, teradata

```
SELECT EVENT_DT - ((EVENT_DT -DATE'1900-01-07') MOD 7) AS dates,
       CLSFD_USER_ID AS user_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CLSFD_USER_ID) AS number_of_user_ids,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CLSFD_CAS_AD_ID) AS number_of_ads,
       SUM(IMPRSN_CNT) AS number_of_impressions
FROM clsfd_access_views.CLSFD_CAS_AD_HST
WHERE CLSFD_SITE_ID = 3001
AND datum >= '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I want to have the total number of unique users during each month of the year 2017. I tried:

```
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum), 2
```

But this returns an error. What would be the most efficient code to retrieve the total number of user ids, ads, and impressions, per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me to be aggregating by users, since they are what you are trying to count.  Try grouping by the month and year alone:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_DT) || '-' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_DT) AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CLSFD_USER_ID) AS number_of_user_ids,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CLSFD_CAS_AD_ID) AS number_of_ads,
    SUM(IMPRSN_CNT) AS number_of_impressions
FROM clsfd_access_views.CLSFD_CAS_AD_HST
WHERE
    CLSFD_SITE_ID = 3001 AND
    datum >= '2017-01-01' AND datum < '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_DT) || '-' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_DT);
```

Note that I changed your restriction on `datum` to also exclude any year greater than 2017.

Comment: slight problem that you do not have 'datum' anymore so you cannot refer to that in your WHERE statement. But I am now trying what you are suggesting, stupid that I didn't think of it myself.

Comment: @StephenTheunissen Having `datum` in the `WHERE` clause is not a problem, because the `WHERE` clause gets evaluated on the entire table before `GROUP BY` happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this values to be included in current query, then you should use analytical functions. For example "total number of unique users during each month" would be something like:

```
select count(distinct user_id) over(partition by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum))
```

Be aware that those values will be repeated for each user.

Comment: Teradata doesn't allow `distinct` in OLAP functions